# Error creating confusion matrix although label encoding done on target variable and feature variable

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am repeatedly getting this error while creating a confusion matrix. My feature variable as well as target variable are all labelEncoded but still don't know why its generating this error.

**Error:**
C:\Users\Strat Com\PycharmProjects\IGN Review\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:261: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison

**ValueError:** At least one label specified must be in y_true

**Note:** Code for the explanation and data set are attached.
Using Windows 10 and running all of this code on Jupyter Notebook

[Link of Data Set](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HC-2LcbP36use7H8XjEx5-8DKXeN9ate)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

DataFrame=pd.read_csv("DataSet.txt",sep='\t',low_memory=False,skip_blank_lines=True)        # Loading the data into the Data Frame
DataFrame=DataFrame.dropna(how='all')
half_count=len(DataFrame)/2
DataFrame=DataFrame.dropna(thresh=half_count,axis=1)                                        # Dropping any column with more than 50% missing values

FrameExplorer = pd.DataFrame(DataFrame.dtypes,columns=['dtypes'])
FrameExplorer=FrameExplorer.reset_index()
FrameExplorer=FrameExplorer.rename(columns={'index':'ColumnName'})

drop_list=['IDShop','PaymentDay','ShopRank','OtherCards','QuantBankAccounts','ApplicationBooth','InsuranceOption']
DataFrame=DataFrame.drop(drop_list,axis=1)


DataFrame = DataFrame.loc[:,DataFrame.apply(pd.Series.nunique) != 1]                        # Getting all the columns which dont have 1 unique value

for cols in DataFrame.columns:  
    if (len(DataFrame[cols].unique())<4):
        print (DataFrame[cols].value_counts())

null_counts = DataFrame.isnull().sum()
print("Number of Null count in each column \n{}".format(null_counts))

# Here we would remove the column containing more than 1% of the rows contains null values So from above column names so
# "Sex" and "Reference 2" would be dropped as they contain approx 10% of rows of missing values

DataFrame=DataFrame.drop(['Sex','Reference2'],axis=1)

DataFrame=DataFrame.dropna()                      # Dropping rows containing missing values to make data more cleaner

DataFrame=DataFrame.drop('Reference1',axis=1)

# Now we would be Label Encoding the columns of object dataType as shown above as they contain only "Y" and "N" Value 

FeatureEncoder=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

DataFrame['MaritalStatus']=FeatureEncoder.fit_transform(DataFrame['MaritalStatus'])
DataFrame['ResidencialPhone']=FeatureEncoder.fit_transform(DataFrame['ResidencialPhone'])
DataFrame['ResidenceType']=FeatureEncoder.fit_transform(DataFrame['ResidenceType'])
DataFrame['MothersName']=FeatureEncoder.fit_transform(DataFrame['MothersName'])
DataFrame['FathersName']=FeatureEncoder.fit_transform(DataFrame['FathersName'])
DataFrame['WorkingTown']=FeatureEncoder.fit_transform(DataFrame['WorkingTown'])
DataFrame['WorkingState']=FeatureEncoder.fit_transform(DataFrame['WorkingState'])
DataFrame['PostalAddress']=FeatureEncoder.fit_transform(DataFrame['PostalAddress'])

# Now we will start to split the data into training set and testing set to train the model and then test it 

cols = [col for col in DataFrame.columns if col not in ['Label']]           # Label is the Target Feature
FeatureData=DataFrame[cols]                                                 # Feature Variables
TargetData=DataFrame['Label']                                               # Target Variables

#split data set into train and test sets
FeatureData_Train, FeatureData_Test, TargetData_Train, TargetData_Test = train_test_split(FeatureData,TargetData, test_size = 0.30, random_state = 10)


type(FeatureData_Train)
type(TargetData_Train)

# Next we will be feeding all of the split done above to the model 

neighbor=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)                     # Creating an Object of KNN Classifier

neighbor.fit(FeatureData_Train,TargetData_Train)                 # Training the model to classify
PredictionData=neighbor.predict(FeatureData_Test)                # Predicting the Response 

# evaluate accuracy
print ("KNeighbors accuracy score : ",accuracy_score(TargetData_Test, PredictionData))


from yellowbrick.classifier import ClassificationReport
from yellowbrick.classifier import ConfusionMatrix

# Instantiate the classification model and visualizer
visualizer = ClassificationReport(neighbor, classes=['0','1'])

visualizer.fit(FeatureData_Train,TargetData_Train)             # Fit the training data to the visualizer
visualizer.score(FeatureData_Test,TargetData_Test)             # Evaluate the model on the test data
g = visualizer.poof()                                          # Draw/show/poof the data

cm = ConfusionMatrix(neighbor, classes=['0','1'])

cm.fit(FeatureData_Train,TargetData_Train)
cm.score(FeatureData_Test,TargetData_Test)
```

Comment: The link to the data set does not work.

Comment: @TomaszR Sorry about that. Link to the data set fixed

Comment: now it's fine, cheers

Comment: @TomaszR Its working now thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Glad to help. If you find my answer useful, could you please accept it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the data type of classes you provided and the ones in the data set are different. In the data you have type float, while you defined classes (in the 3rd line from the end of the file) as strings.

Simply change that line to:

```
cm = ConfusionMatrix(neighbor, classes=[0,1])
```

and it will work fine.